# Headers don't show up in Dev C++

Tags: c++, header-files, dev-c++, c++98, turbo-c++

I am trying to do this super basic hello world code in dev c++ and i am getting this errors

I tried searching the web for relevant answers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio>
void main()
{
cout<<"hello";
getch();
}
```

The error that I get is:

```
[Error] conio: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
recipe for target '"Hello world.o"' failed
```

Since I first learnt java I am quit familiar to this simple code and I always wonder why c++ is not as easy as java is

```
public class HelloWorld
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    System.out.println("Hello World");
}

}
```

Note:It doesn't need those the use of int and return type and stuff like c++ does

I need a way better than this one without using
1) "using namespace std" 
2) "int main and return 0"
3) "void::main"
and other things like that

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "Hello, world!";
return 0;
}
```

A sweet and simple solution as that of java.

Thank you.

P. S. I typed the exact same program in turbo C++ and it works perfectly and gives the desired output

Comment: There is no such Standard C++ header as `<conio>`. Try learning the language before complaining about it.

Comment: @Valay_17 Java is **not** C++.  Do not come into learning C++ trying to make it look like Java.  It just doesn't work out too well if you do this.

Comment: Agree @PaulMcKenzie but I am asking for a tangible solution to the problem that I am facing.

Comment: Unless you remove Java from memory, you will never learn C++.

Comment: [Hello World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program#/media/File:Hello_World_Brian_Kernighan_1978.jpg)

Comment: Turbo C++ is more than two decades out of date and doesn't even support C++98, let alone C++17. Don't waste time learning anything from a resource focused on Turbo C++, that's just wasting your time learning things you are going to have to un-learn again.

Comment: @JesperJuhl what is C++98 & 17 ?? Explain please

Comment: @Valay_17 They are revisions of the standardized C++ language. Version 98 was the first and 17 is the current one. C++20 is currently in the process of being finalized. The number refers to the year of publication of the standard. There's also C++03, C++11 and C++14 See also: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17 . Turbo C++ predates even the first standard and supports none of the features those standards introduce. It also uses many features of the language that were dropped when it was standardized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dev C++ uses C++17 while Turbo C++ uses C++98 which are the different versions of C++.
This is the reason why your code is not working

Answer (score 2):

The shortest and simplest way I can think of to write this would be

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
}
```

1) `main` *must* return `int` in C++. But main is also special in that it's the *only* function that will implicitly return `0` if you don't return a value. So you can drop the `return 0;`.

2) `using namespace std;` is not needed (and actively discouraged). You just need to explicitly qualify functions you call in that namespace.

3) There is no `conio` header in standard C++.

Comment: Can you explain the use of std::cout please??

Comment: `cout` is defined in the `std` namespace, so since you removed `using namespace std;`, you must prefix the `cout` with the `std` namespace.

Comment: Side note: `main` must return `int` *in a hosted environment*. Otherwise it is implementation dependent and `void main` is the most popular one

Comment: @Ayxan True, in a *free standing* impletation, the rules are different. But I would be *very* surprised if OP was not using a hosted impletation.